# Gitlab CI ERROR: Job failed: exit status 123

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти расшифровку кодов ошибок Gitlab CI?
При пуше коммита фэйлится на стадии compile с ошибкой

$ $env:Path
���⠪����᪠� �訡�� � ����� 䠩��, ����� ����� ��� ��⪥ ⮬�.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 123

До этого раннер был настроен на другой машине и у другого человека и стадия компиляции проходила успешно, пытаюсь найти свою ошибку.

Comment: Русские буквы в пути?

Comment: Нет русских букв в пути, можно рассматривать сообщение без предыдущих двух строк на самом деле: ERROR: Job failed: exit status 123. Так как строки непонятными символами были и когда компилировалось без ошибки